# Find all local extremes of a function with parameter.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

$$f(x,y)=xy+e^{a(x^2+y^2)}$$
I calculated all the first- and second-order partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y+2axe^{a(x^2+y^2)}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x+2aye^{a(x^2+y^2)}\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x} = 2ae^{a(x^2+y^2)}(1+2ax^2)\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 y} = 2ae^{a(x^2+y^2)}(1+2ay^2)\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = 1+4a^2xye^{a(x^2+y^2)}
$$
But checking if the Hessian matrix is definite for every case is really tedious. Is there another way?

Comment: What are the critical points?

Comment: Local extrema occur only when the first order partial derivatives are both 0. There are not that many cases. In fact, I only find 5.

Comment: The problem is not finding where the first order partial derivative is 0, but the fact that the determinant of Hessian matrix becomes very complicated with logarithms.

Comment: I can see critical points where x=y=0 and a is a real number, where x=y and y^2=(ln(-(1/(2a)))), or where x^2+y^2=(ln(1/(2a)))/a

Comment: ... You just have to do the computations... Think of them as character building..